# Modifying Jquery Mobile Viewport by Simple Query

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, viewport

I have looked at numerous answers here on StackExchange and feel I'm getting close but still one last problem.  What I'm trying to do is - if my mobile page has a table in it set a specified viewport and if not then set another defined viewport.  Here's the essential code ...

```
    <title>Howdy</title>
<meta name="viewport" id="viewportid"  />

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myvp;
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function() {
        //  alert("PageCreate Done!");
        alert($('table:visible').length);
        var numTablesOnPage = $('table:visible').length;
        if (numTablesOnPage > 0)
        {
            $("table:visible").each(function() {

                if ($(this).width() > screen.width) {
                    var tableWidth = $(this).width();
                    alert("Table Width: " + $(this).width());
                    alert("Screen Wdith: " + screen.width);
                    myvp= document.getElementById('viewportid');
                    myvp.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("no tables");
            mvp = document.getElementById('viewportid');
            mvp.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
        }
    });
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

    </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried this with a table in my html and without just to try out both branches of my if/else statement and I get the expected defined alerts I've included.

```
 myvp.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes");
```

It doesn't appear to apply/update my viewport settings regardless of the if/else branch that was used.  I've checked in the chrome debugger and nothing.   I have a feeling it's the pagebefore event.  I've tried pageshow and pagebeforeshow. Am I trying to change the viewport at the wrong part of the page cycle?  Am I on the right track?  Any other ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that if I replaced this code -

```
          mvp = document.getElementById('viewportid');
        mvp.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");
```

with this -

```
  $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">');
```

then my viewport was being dynamically set and working as expected.